# GeoJSON data not displayed on a vector layer

Tags: geojson, openlayers-3

I'm trying to display a vector layer to show a set of geojson features.

When I try and add the layer though I get an error in the ol.js library "k.xd is not a function"

```
var geoData = {"type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":
    [
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"Name":"","Description":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0.0,0.0]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"Name":"1","Description":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[11.50728,3.87471,0.0]}},
    ]
};

// vector layer
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoData)
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
          })
        })
    });
```

I've hacked together an example here http://jsfiddle.net/dxt95yt6/1/ that shows it not working but I can't figure out where this differs from the original tutorials.

Comment: I played around with in on jsfiddle.  I swapped out your data with the openlayers geoJSON example data and it worked fine, so I would assume the problem is in your geojson data itself.  I noticed it was missing a snippet at the top regarding the CRS, see the top of the sample data on the geojson example.  I added in the EPSG code for NAD83, still didn't show.  Sorry I can't be of more help but I can tell you that the code itself is working, it's just the geojson source data that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given style object is not correct for points and therefore features just don't show up. Try:

```
style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 8,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 2
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
        })
    })
})
```

Please note, in original code, there's another problem, too. Coordinates have to be transformed to EPSG:3857:

```
features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(
    geoData,
    {featureProjection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')}
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqx6644q/8/

Comment: This was it.  As I was passing a stroke not a circle for a single point it's not going to show much of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Its always helpful to validate your geojson before using it. I can recommend [geojsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com/) which has alos an api to make sure your using a correct geojson.

Comment: Actually the example json in that very web page is where I started from with equally no success.

Comment: Beside the correct answer above, you should only add two coordinates to a point (regarding the second one)

Comment: No it is valid to contain more than 2 coordinates to account for altitude and the specification doesn't limit it to 3 either though it doesn't enforce what those values mean. http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions

Comment: Ah, you are right, thanks for clearing me up. I checked the validator again and it seems its only the last comma in the features array which is out of format.